# Android carousel OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, carousel

I want to create sth like this [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ke9tTCzkRTg) using OpenGL ES 2.0. I am still a beginner, and I did the basic tutorials like drawing a square, quad etc. but still don't have a precise idea how i should do this. Should I create GLES20SurfaceView and somehow use it combined with a gallery widget (every item of the gallery would be a view - GLES20SurfaceView) or I should draw everything from scratch. Please, if someone has an experience with similar things and done sth like this, let me know, give some hints, examples, links, everything would be of great help.

Comment: It's been two years now, did you get any good examples or demo regarding this carousel? i would really like any kind of help regarding this

Answer (score 0):

[Gallery](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) is specific to a horizontal scrolling list, and wouldn't apply here.

You will want one GL surface view for your entire drawable area, not individual ones for each item.

The Carousel youtube item was created using [RenderScript](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/package-summary.html) for best performance.

You can accomplish similar functionality entirely in Java, although performance may be an issue.  I suggest writing it in Java first, then optimizing as needed for your application.  [Here is an Android OpenGL ES 2.0 tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es20.html).

Comment: yes I assumed that I would need to use one GL surface view for the entire area. Thank u for your response! but still kind of without a precise idea of how would i do the whole implementation..

Comment: I'm going to suggest that you start simple and expand as you want to add features.  Write the code to draw a square.  Expand it to make the square a cube.  Put images on four of the cube's sides.  Then move the camera to the middle of the cube and make sure you have culling set correctly.  Now, make the cube spin.  Now make the cube spin according to a finger swipe.  Now increase the number of sides in the cube.  etc

Comment: thx for the suggestion but as i said i did the basic tutorials and still need an advice how to progress into building a gallery like implementation. Also I can't use renderscript because i need to create this for android 2.2 version.

Comment: My previous comment is my advice.  Each step outlined is basic by itself.  Put together, you will have a carousel.  Maybe someone else will be able to help you better.